# Browser animation glitch react-spring

Tags: reactjs, animation, browser, frame, react-spring

I am building an animated grid with react-spring. Elements are animated from previous to next position. Positions are calculated to fit elements depending on width and their margins.

### The problem

There is a glitch when the animation `enter`s that halts the animation for a fraction of a second when the page first loads. This can be seen clearly on the browser page (latest Chrome and Firefox). The glitch is bearly visible in the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hard-grid-7d6ui?file=/src/App.js), but also happens there.

The gif example animation provided makes the glitch more obvious. The behavior on browser can be reproduced by downloading the code sandbox and `npm start`.

### Thoughts

I believe this has to do with the browser loading and some frames being dropped during that.

### Questions

- How to avoid frames being dropped due to browser load if that is the case?
- Above all: how to avoid the glitch, and what possible workarounds can you see? (e.g: Loading animated elements after page completely loads)

Additional question: I also observe that the end part of the animation is kinda funky with a very low step, is this expected behavior? What would the ideal config look like to avoid that...?

[image: GIF example animation]

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm facing the same issue, as well as laggy/choppy animations on mobile devices (mobile browsing).

Comment: @thexpand I did, I kept on experimenting back then, but I can't recall just now. Feel free to go through the sandbox that's linked and check out the repo I used https://github.com/mikemajara/react-spring-animated-grid

Comment: I just ended up rewriting everything in `framer-motion`. Sadly, ditching `react-spring` was the best thing to do...